# Override frontend JS for Woocommerce Checkout

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I need to hide the billing address, city, state and zip fields when the checkout page is loaded in order to use our address validation script. The code below accomplishes what we want but it does it too late in the process. You see the fields until it runs the `updated_checkout` event which is too late in the process. However running it on `init_checkout` seems to be too early as there is something else forcing those fields to be displayed. Is there something in between `init_checkout` and `updated_checkout` that I should be watching for?

```
jQuery( "body" ).on( "updated_checkout", function() {
  jQuery("#billing_country_field,
  #billing_address_1_field
  #billing_address_2_field,
  #billing_city_field,
  #billing_state_field,
  #billing_postcode_field").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: Invoke your functionality on both events? `jQuery( "body" ).on( "init_checkout updated_checkout", function(){ ...`

Comment: The problem is that it won't work on `init_checkout` as there seems to be something else that displays the fields afterwards.

Comment: Here is a demo on page load. https://www.dropbox.com/s/f0b6ec7v3meje67/checkout.gif?dl=0

Comment: Why not just load the script via wp_enqueue_scripts?  I've seen other address plugins do this and it works to hide the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the DOM is first loaded, the fields will appear anyway.

I have tried with all available javascript events delegated from "body": `added_to_cart` `adding_to_cart` `change` `click` `country_to_state_changed` `country_to_state_changing` `init_checkout` `update_checkout` `updated_wc_div` `wc_fragment_refresh` `wc_fragment_refreshed`.
The fields will always appear a bit.

The only way is to hide checkout form when loading with some CSS rules that you will add to your active theme `styles.css` file:

```css
form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout{
    visibility:hidden;
    opacity:0;
}
```

And a bit of jQuery that will first hide your fields, before displaying the checkout form:

```
add_filter( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_script' );
function custom_checkout_script( ){
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var events = 'update_checkout',
            billingFields = '#billing_country_field,#billing_address_1_field,#billing_address_2_field';
        billingFields += ',#billing_city_field,#billing_state_field,#billing_postcode_field';

        $('body').on( events, function(){
            $(billingFields).hide( 0,function(){
                $('form.checkout.woocommerce-checkout').css('visibility','visible').fadeIn({ duration: 1000 });
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

All code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works.

Comment: While this doesn't solve the issue, it seems to be the best option at the moment. Thanks